# Constant string arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, constants

Is it possible to have a (fixed) array which stores its elements in the read-only segment of the executable and not on the stack? I came up with this code but unfortunately it is very unflexible when it comes to adding, moving or deleting items. How do I verify that the strings are indeed stored in the read-only segment? I tried *readelf -a file* but it doesn't list the strings.

```
typedef struct {
        int len;
        int pos[100];
        char data[500];
} FixedStringArray;

const FixedStringArray items = {
        4,
        { 9, 14, 19, 24 },
        "LongWord1Word2Word3Word4"
} ;

char* GetItem(FixedStringArray *array, int idx, int *len) {
        if (idx >= array->len) {
                /* Out of range */
                *len = -1;
                return NULL;
        }

        if (idx > 0) {
                *len = array->pos[idx] - array->pos[idx - 1];
                return & array->data[array->pos[idx - 1]];
        }

        *len = array->pos[idx];
        return & array->data[0];
}

void PrintItem(FixedStringArray array, int idx) {
        int len;
        char *c;
        int i = 0;

        c = GetItem(&array, idx, &len);

        if (len == -1) return;

        while (i < len) {
                printf("%c", *c);
                *c++;
                i++;
        }
}
```

I am considering a script that automatically generates a struct for each array and uses the correct length for *pos* and *data*. Are there any concerns in terms of memory usage?
Or would it be better to create one struct (like above) to fit all strings?

Answer (score 31):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but do you mean:

```
const char * const array[] = { "LongWord1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4" };
```

This declares a constant array of pointers to constant characters.

OK, to avoid strlen, how about:

```
struct Str {
    size_t len;
    char *str;
};
#define STR(s) { sizeof(#s) - 1, #s }
const struct Str[] = { STR(LongWord1), STR(Word2), STR(Word3), STR(Word4) };
```

Comment: Okay, that would make things easier indeed but I prefer not to use NUL termination for strings. I do not want to depend on external functions such as strlen() just to get the length considering it can be also calculated during on compile time (using sizeof()-1).

Comment: What does that "#" mean in front of the s?

Comment: # turns the macro argument into a string e.g. longword1 becomes "longword1".

Answer (score 1):

Can't your C compiler stick any/all literal strings into read-only memory (e.g. VC++ with string pooling enabled)?  Or do you explicitly require them to be stored sequentially in that way?

Comment: Yes, the former would be also fine. Shouldn't GCC do that already by default for all const variables?

Answer (score 0):

This question is somewhat relevant:
[String Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718477/string-literals)

As pointed out, the storage of string literals in ROM/RAM is platform/implementation dependent, you should not make any predictions for that. Also using a script to read and create array of appropriate sizes and store them is quite undesirable. You should better go for [dynamic memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation).

Comment: Thanks for the link. But how is the ROM/RAM difficulty related to my problem? I do not write to the string buffer during runtime. Since the elements are all fixed, there is no sense in using dynamic memory.