# constant char * in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Can you help me to clarify why this instruction fails?:

```
char * p = "string";
p[0] = 'a';
```

I have read in http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html that a string literal...

```
turns into an unnamed, static array of characters,
and this unnamed array may be stored in read-only memory
```

and this in http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers:

```
String literals are arrays of the proper array type to contain all
its characters plus the terminating null-character, with each of the
elements being of type const char
```

This is not completely clear for me:

1. both concepts refer to the same thing?
2. if not, which one is correct?
3. is every constant stored in read-only memory?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behaviour. There are a lot of duplicate questions on this topic on SO already.

Comment: `char *` pointing to a string literal is deprecated in C++ and invalid as of C++11.

Comment: Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/718477/10077