# storage of character pointer in memory

Tags: c++, string, character

1a) There is this code

```
char *p;
p[0]='a';
p[1]='b';
printf("%s",p);
```

When i run this program on ideone.com compiler: c++ 4.3.2, it displays "RUNTIME ERROR" every single time i run it.

1b). however when i edit this code to

```
char *p;
//allocate memory using malloc
p[0]='a';
p[1]='b';
printf("%s",p);
```

It correctly runs and prints "ab" . shouldn't it require the p[2]='\0' at the end?

2)

```
char *p;
p="abc"
printf("%s",p);
```

this correctly runs and prints "abc"  . why does this work without allocation.

Can anyone please explain the rules regarding string storage ?

Comment: 1b): depends on how you allocate your memory, if what `p` points to hasn't been zeroed and isn't at least 3 chars long then you have UB. 2): see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718477/string-literals

Answer (score 4):

**1a)** **undefined behavior** because you dereference a non initialized pointer

**1b)** **undefined behavior** since you call `printf` with `%s` for a non null terminated string

**2)** works ok: there is an allocation, it just is a string literal (you can't modify it, it is stored in the read-only portion of the program : you should declare it `const char*` for that reason)

**Note:**

In C++, use `std::string` and `std::cout` .

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you declare a pointer to `char` and then you assign values to undefined locations in memory. Undefined because its what the uninitialize `p` pointer points to. You need to allocate memory for the sequence (with `new[]` in C++, not `malloc`). If you do not put a `'\0'` at the end, printing will stop at the first 0 encountered in memory.

In the third example you are declaring a pointer to `char` and initialize its value with the address of the literal string `"abc"`. That is stored in the (read-only) data section in the executable and that gets map to the process address space. So that's a valid pointer and your printing works.

Comment: why not with malloc ?

Answer (score 1):

1a) here you don't allocate memory, so the p pointer points to a random place, therefore causing segfault when you write that random location

1b) if you allocate memory manually with malloc, it will work correctly. If the allocated memory contains 0s, you don't have to add it manually (but you should, because you can't count on the zero filling)

2) here you assign the p pointer to the string literal "abs", so it will point to it, and the allocation is done by the compiler

Comment: 1b) so, you're saying there must be a 0 present after the 'b' ?

Comment: @guitar_geek yes, otherwise you'd see garbage, like "ab@#$@#(*GDFS". To be sure that will not happen, add p[2] = '\0'; (and don't forget to allocate enough memory, in this case 3*sizeof(char))