# Universal reference template type always evaluate to lvalue

Tags: c++, string, function, rvalue, lvalue

My code:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

void store(std::string & val)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue " << val << '\n';
}

void store(std::string && val)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue " << val << '\n';
}

template<typename T> void print(T && val)
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value << " ";
    store(std::forward<T>(val));
}

int main()
{
    std::string val("something");
    print(val);
    print("something else");
}
```

my output:

```
true lvalue something
true rvalue something else
```

I've read on Universal referencing and understand why T is a lvalue when the input is a lvalue but I don't understand how is T a lvalue when the input is a rvalue, how does that collapse to the right paramter?

Comment: string literals are lvalues.

Comment: @T.C right, thanks... stupid mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand how is T a lvalue when the input is a rvalue, how does that collapse to the right paramter?

No, the input is not an rvalue.

String literals are lvalues, and that's what you pass as a parameter to the function. That's why "true" is printed.

Now, recall that *string literals cannot be modified* ([String Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718477/string-literals)).

So, "something else" is of lenght 14 + 1 (for the null terminator), thus a `const char[15]`.

Now, since string literals cannot be modified, the reference will be deduced as:

```
 const char(&)[15];
```

The prototype of your method is:

```
store(std::string && val)
```

which creates a temporary `std::string` from `const char`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not the forwarding reference. It's that you aren't passing a `std::string` rvalue to the function.

You are passing a string literal that is 15 character long, its type is `const char[15]`. And string literals are non-modifiable lvalues, so the reference is deduced as `const char (&)[15]`.

The reason you see your rvalue overload printing is because, well, you can construct a temporary `std::string` out of a character array.

Comment: nice answer, I posted one, but you were 36 seconds faster, so +1! However I don't get your first sentence..Other than that we seem to agree! :D

Comment: @gsamaras - Thanks. My first sentence is about the OP's title. Their assumption that the reference deduces to an lvalue when it shouldn't.